# Changing Unit Configuration to restart httpd every 3s

Tags: systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I tried to add the following with `systemctl edit httpd.service` and this created `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/override.conf`containing :

```
[Unit]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

now after `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart httpd` I waited for 3s and checking the PID of httpd and it's not changing.

why the service is not restarting ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Restart=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) doesn’t instruct systemd to kill and restart a service periodically, it describes whether systemd should restart a service if it dies or is killed.

You‘ll see the effects of your changes if you kill `httpd` yourself: after three seconds, it will be restarted.

Comment: Thank you, It restarted after killing the process